# Meaning of "...motor...pushes the wheels around."

Tags: meaning-in-context, listening

In this [audio file](http://ilielearning-sd.ir/content/lessons/13/Intermediate3_2/unit_7/listening/listening.mp3), what does the man say at 2:32? Is it:

> Now, this motor in the back pushes the wheels *around*.

If so, what does *push something around* mean in this context?

Source: *The ILI English Series, Intermediate 3, Student's book, Page 101*

Comment: It is as you say. "Pushes the wheels around" means "turns the wheels round".

Comment: It means it "turns" the wheels around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audio file does indeed say what you think it does.

What this means is that the motor turns the wheels – it rotates them through 360°. Consider the definitions of *push* and *around*:

> [**push**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/push)
>   *Verb*
>   *[with object, usually with adverbial]* Exert force on (someone or something),
>   typically with one's hand, in order to move them away from oneself or the
>   origin of the force.
>
> *"she pushed her glass toward him"*
>   *[with object and complement] "Lydia pushed the door shut"*
>   *[no object] "he pushed at the skylight, but it wouldn't budge"*
>
> ---
>
> [**around**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/around)
>   *Adverb*
>   **1.3** With circular motion:
>
> *"the boats were spun around by waterspouts"*

This isn't, however, the only meaning of the phrase. In other contexts, *push around* might be the phrasal verb:

> [**push someone around**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/push_someone_around)
>   *Phrasal verb*
>   *informal* Treat someone roughly or inconsiderately.
>
> *"You must hold your head up high and not allow those bullies to push you
>   around"*

It might also refer to pushing something *around* an obstacle, it may mean pushing it *around* (i.e. through the circumference of) a space, or it could be in the context of a child playing with food (*pushing* the vegetables *around* their plate):

> [**around**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/around)
>   *Adverb*
>   **1.4** So as to cover or take in the whole area surrounding a particular
>   center.
>
> **3** *British* So as to reach a new place or position, typically by
>   moving from one side of something to the other.
>
> **4** Randomly or unsystematically; here and there.

If you encounter the phrase again in another or unfamiliar context, a dictionary will be your friend.

Comment: "If you encounter the phrase again in another or unfamiliar context, a dictionary will be your friend." Thanks for the answer and referring me to a dictionary! Actually my main problem was that I wasn't sure what he said with a German accent!

Answer (score 1):

When I hear or read "push the wheels around" I think of an old train wheel [driveshaft](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/driveshaft):

[image]

The *engine* turns a *gear* (or [a *cam*](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/cam)) that moves the *shaft* backward and forward.  The shaft pushes against the *wheel* to transform the back-and-forth motion into rotational motion.

There are, of course, many, many other designs that have similar action.  For example, [this is a four-stroke engine with a similar mechanism](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dc/4StrokeEngine_Ortho_3D_Small.gif):